# create an invisible widget that binds to keypressed

Tags: odoo

I want to create an invisible widget that binds to keypressed anywhere on the webclient after the login.

I have tried to extent Widget

but as i don't need to render anything , i don't know how to put it in the html on screen.

should i try to extent some other class in OpenErp to get this working?

```
console.log('start')  // Custome message to dispaly on console
openerp.web_hello = function(instance) {


   console.log('Object',instance);

   var invisibleWidget = instance.web.Widget.extend({
        template: 'invisibleWidget',
        init: function(parent){
           this._super(parent);
        },
   });

};
```

Answer (score 1):

Following javascript module is a good start for the solution. Just sharing for others who are interested

```
/*---------------------------------------------------------
 * OpenERP module
 *---------------------------------------------------------*/
openerp.web_keypressed = function(instance) {

    instance.web.InvisibleWidget = instance.web.Widget.extend({
        template: 'InvisibleWidget',
        init: function() {
           this._super.apply(this, arguments);           
           instance.web.InvisibleWidget = this;
        },
        start: function() {
           this._super.apply(this, arguments);           
        },
        sessKeyPressed: function(ed, e) {
           console.log('sessKeyPressed');
        },
   });

   instance.web.WebClient = instance.web.WebClient.extend({       
        show_application: function() {
           this._super.apply(this, arguments);
           var self = this;
           console.log('webclient extend');
           self.invisible = new instance.web.InvisibleWidget(this);           
           self.invisible.appendTo(self.$el);           
           console.log(instance.web.InvisibleWidget);
           $(document).bind('keypress.session', function (ed, e) {
               instance.web.InvisibleWidget.sessKeyPressed(ed, e);
           });
        },
   });

};
```